# LOCK TABLE public.users_receipthash IN ACCESS SHARE MODE

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to run:

```
pg_dump database_name > database_name_08_27_2018
```

but got these errors:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation users_receipthash

pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.users_receipthash IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

How can I fix this? Ubuntu 16.04 server

Answer (score 2):

lets assume you have table:

`t=# create table users_receipthash();
CREATE TABLE`

you either need to be owner of it:

```
t=# \dt users_receipthash
             List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  | Owner
--------+-------------------+-------+-------
 public | users_receipthash | table | vao
(1 row)
```

or have owner role granted for you

```
t=# grant vao to root;
GRANT ROLE
```

or be a superuser:

```
t=# \du vao
              List of roles
 Role name | Attributes |    Member of
-----------+------------+-----------------
 vao       | Superuser  | {dba, PostgresRules}
```

if you not and you want to be one, run as sueruser

```
t=# alter user vao superuser;
ALTER ROLE
```

Now I use **you** referring to the db user you use connecting to database. You ommit `-U` key on connection string, thus I assume you use peer authentication for your os user. in my case I use os user *vao* (and db user *vao* )